# Combinations generator

Tags: python, python-itertools

Have a list x of truck loading points

With itertools generated the all possible routes:

```
import itertools
comb=[]
x=['1','2','3','4','5']
for a in range(1,len(x)+1):
    s=list(itertools.permutations(x,a))
    comb.extend(s)
print(comb)
```

Now the task to list all possible combinations of truck routes with qty of trucks<=len(x), like:

```py
[['1'],['2'],['3'],['4'],['5']]
[['1','2','3','4','5']]
[['1'],['2','3'],['4','5']]
[['1','2','3'],['4','5']]
[['1'],['2','3'],['4','5']]
...
```

The main criteria to ensure, that all of elements of list x are inside of each combinations, other words: to generate all possible combinations of truck routes with number or trucks from 1 to len(x) and make sure, that we picked from each point only once.

Which way to generate algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried using `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: Are `[['1'],['2','3'],['4','5']]` and `[['1'],['3','2'],['4','5']]` different routes in your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by getting the individual sizes of chunks that can contain the data. Here's a simple recursive generator that can do so:

```
def route_sizes(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        for sizes in route_sizes(n-i):
            yield [i, *sizes]
    yield [n]


for sizes in route_sizes(5):
    print(sizes)
```

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 3]
...
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 2]
[4, 1]
[5]
```

Now that you have the sizes, you can use them to actually split the data. You can use itertools.accumlate to help with this.

```
def create_routes(data):
    for sizes in route_sizes(len(data)):
        yield [
            data[end-size:end]
            for size, end in zip(sizes, itertools.accumulate(sizes))
        ]


for route in create_routes(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']):
    print(route)
```

```
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5']]
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4', '5']]
[['1'], ['2'], ['3', '4'], ['5']]
[['1'], ['2'], ['3', '4', '5']]
...
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4'], ['5']]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5']]
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5']]
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the `itertools.combinations` function.

```
import itertools


def main(x: list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], combinations: list = []) -> list:
    for n in range(1, len(x) + 1):
        for combination in itertools.combinations(x, n):
            combinations.append(
                list(
                    combination
                )
            )

    # combinações que não contêm os pontos do array x
    combinations = [c for c in combinations if set(c) == set(x)]
    
    # combinações repetidas
    combinations = [
        c for c in combinations if len(c) == len(
            set(c)
        )
    ]

    return combinations


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).